# Laravel multi-tenant app works properly in local but does not work in production/staging

Tags: multi-tenant, laravel-5.6, php-7.1

I build a multi-tenant app in laravel, That works properly in local but it does not work on production/staging. Whenever I try to login, it shows an error that : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tenancy.users' doesn't exist.

I have already run migrations and also try php artisan config:ca.

**Package used :** composer require "hyn/multi-tenant:5.3.*"

**.env :**

```
LIMIT_UUID_LENGTH_32=true

APP_URL_BASE=testdomain

APP_URL=http://${APP_URL_BASE}

DB_CONNECTION=system

TENANCY_HOST=127.0.0.1

TENANCY_PORT=3306

TENANCY_DATABASE=tenancy

TENANCY_USERNAME=root

TENANCY_PASSWORD=
```

**database.php :**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'tenant'),
 ....

 'system' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('TENANCY_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('TENANCY_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('TENANCY_DATABASE', 'tenancy'),
        'username' => env('TENANCY_USERNAME', 'tenancy'),
        'password' => env('TENANCY_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'tenant' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('TENANCY_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('TENANCY_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('TENANCY_DATABASE', 'tenancy'),
        'username' => env('TENANCY_USERNAME', 'tenancy'),
        'password' => env('TENANCY_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

I also built a laraval mts, with laravel 8. It works locally and i have run into a similar issue.

1. ensure your .htaccess file is correct. Mine runs in cpanel and i found it was being overwritten everytime i updated the repo with master
2. make sure you have the databases set up. I use phpmyadmin on cpanel so i had to build the databases.
3. create a database user and give them access rights to the databases.
4. update .env to use your newly created database user